# Why does my dumpling /dimsum/momos turn dark brown while steaming?

Tags: dumplings

We make dumplings by bun making machine. (bought from China.)

We add all purpose flour, xanthan gum and water to make the dough for dumpling. 
We make 10 varieties of dumpling and filling varies as per the variety. After making the dumplings, we half steam and sell it to the market. When we half steam at our kitchen, everything if fine.

But some of our dumplings turns pale yellow when our client resteams at their sale point. If steamed more, it turns into dark brown colour.

What could be the problem?

Also, our dumplings breaks too much. What can be done?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE. :)

Comment: Do you know what steamer (and materials) your client use?

Comment: That dark brown looks like burning. Is it running too hot on the clients side?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the color, it looks like your dumplings might be exposed to too high a heat on a surface that could actually sear them (that metal pan for example). It also looks like those dumplings might be overcrowded and being handled too much so that they'd break.

If it's possible, I'd see what your clients are doing to prepare the dumplings you send them and make sure it's not an issue with their technique.

Comment: If it's steamed like in the top photo in the question, pot is definitely overcrowded and it would explain everything you mention in your answer.